# Android Google Place Picker: no nearby places until map pan

Tags: google-places-api, picker, google-places, gmsplacepicker

When the place picker launches, there is a 3-5 second long loading circle animation next to where the nearby places list should appear. After the loading circle disappears, no nearby places are shown in the list, and no nearby places pins are shown on the map.

Now, if pan the map (zoom doesn't do anything) in any direction a fair amount, the nearby places load just fine.

The first image below is taken after the place picker launches, it will stay this way without loading any nearby places until I pan the map.

The second image is taken after I have panned the map, where the nearby places loaded correctly.

At the bottom is my relevant code, let me know if you need more.

[image: Before panning the map]
[image: After panning the map]

```
<manifest
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <application
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>
</manifest>

// Emulator is using google play services version 9.4.52
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:9.4+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4+'
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
            .Builder(this)
            .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
            .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .build();
}

public void choosePlace() {
    try {
        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // This is not being thrown
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // This is not being thrown
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // This is not being called
}
```

Comment: What happens if you go back to your current location after panning the map away? In other words, does it _never_ give you results for your current location, or does it only fail the first time?

Comment: TL;DR :
It never loads nearby places when the map is centered around my current location or very close to it.


I didn't expect this behavior but here it is:
Upon panning away from my current location, i get the places for where i pan to. If i pan back to my location, or very close to it, no places are loaded around my current location. Also if i pan away and use the fab to get back to my location, no places are loaded.
Thank you for prompting this clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this?

```
<meta-data            
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_key" />
```

I had the same issue because I forgot to add meta-data to my manifest

Comment: Yes i have that added